Numerical Sequence Puzzle (?), 51, 110, 1011, 105, 105111, 10101
(?), 51, 110, 1011, 105, 105111, 10101
Got it from a friend, try your best.

Since you edited the body, this no longer matches the title...?

Huh you changed the question completely?

Is the title or the body the correct one?

Now the accepted answer doesn't match the title nor the body.

If seems to easy for SE Puzzling, include a small mislead.

I believe the answer here is

111

Why?

 Roman numerals are involved here:


 Basically the 1 is I, 5 is V, 10 is X
 Breaking up the sequence bearing this in mind we get:
 5 1,1 10,10 1 1,10 5,10 5 1 1 1,10 10 1


  Translating this into Roman Numerals we have ?, VI, IX,XII,XV,XVIII,XXI…
 Or 6,9,12,15,18,21


 These are going up by +3 each time. So ? has to be 3 which is III and III is 111 in the context here.

